# How to check if date is in range regardless of the year

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering what would be the easiest way in MySQL to check if given date is in range regardless of the year.

In database table I have two `DATE` fields: `start` and `finish` stored in `YYYY-mm-dd`

if `start = 2013-11-01` and `finish = 2014-03-01` anything between 1st of November and 1st of March of any year should be accepted.

Valid dates:
`2020-01-01` `1980-02-28`

Invalid dates:
`2013-10-30` `1968-07-30`

Comment: When you say between, do you mean including March 1st, or right up to midnight before March 1st?

Comment: including both start and finish

Comment: your question is a bit unclear, what is your input variable is it one date or a range? Pleasy supply some of the sql you already tried!

Comment: If `start = 2013-10-01` and `end = 2015-11-01`, do you just want to retrieve dates between 10-01 and 11-01. Or because the range spans 13 months do you want to return all dates?

Comment: Only dates between 10-01 and 11-01, as I said "regardless of the Year", therefore it is one month range not 13

Comment: Ok thats what I initially answered for anyway. Wasn't sure if you meant to ignore the year of start and end as well. You should try the answers and give us your results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are almost certainly cleaner ways of doing it, however this should work:

```
((DAYOFYEAR(finish_date) > DAYOFYEAR(start_date) 
    AND (DAYOFYEAR(@date) >= DAYOFYEAR(start_date) 
     AND DAYOFYEAR(@date) <= DAYOFYEAR(finish_date)))
OR (DAYOFYEAR(finish_date) <= DAYOFYEAR(start_date) 
    AND (DAYOFYEAR(@date) >= DAYOFYEAR(start_date) 
      OR DAYOFYEAR(@date) <= DAYOFYEAR(finish_date))))
```

For a start date in Oct 2012 and end date in Nov 2020 this will return all dates in the Oct-Nov range. If in fact would want it to return all Dates when the range is greater than a year (and hence covers all dates of the year) you could add:

```
OR DATEDIFF(Day, start_date, finish_date) > 356
```

before the final bracket.

Comment: this wont work in case of @date = 1968-07-30 in the above example

Comment: with what start and end parameter? how does it fail?

Comment: start = 2013-11-01 and finish = 2014-03-01
set @date = '1968-07-30';
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE ((DAYOFYEAR(`finish_date`) > DAYOFYEAR(`start_date`) 
    AND (DAYOFYEAR(@date) >= DAYOFYEAR(`start_date`) 
     AND DAYOFYEAR(@date) <= DAYOFYEAR(`finish_date`)))
OR (DAYOFYEAR(`finish_date`) <= DAYOFYEAR(`start_date`) 
    AND (DAYOFYEAR(@date) <= DAYOFYEAR(`start_date`) 
      OR DAYOFYEAR(@date) >= DAYOFYEAR(`finish_date`))));

It fails by returning results while it shouldn't

Comment: I'm confused, does the table (`test` in your example) contain the start and end date ranges? Then you input 1 date and want to return all the ranges that the date is within?

Comment: Yes :) btw thanks for trying to help, this looks like a common requirement but its so confusing

Comment: Try the code in my answer now. I was doing some incorrect comparisons

Answer (score 1):

use DAYOFYEAR:

When the Start Date is earlier in the year than the Finished Date:

- the tested Date should lye between Start Date and Finish Date (or on Start or Finish)

When the Finished Date is earlier in the year than the Start Date:

- the tested Date should lye outside the Start Date and Finish Date (or on Start or Finish)

Comment: I can't see how this could work for the given examples, datediff takes into consideration years as well

Comment: Provided new solution

Comment: it will, because you subtract the 1st of January from that year, but I see now that DAYOFYEAR is even simpler

Comment: I mean that you still have to do additional checks to cope. Jan -> March cannot use the same comparison as Dec -> Mar  `Date > Jan AND Date < Mar` will work, `Date > Dec AND Date < Mar` would fail for all records.

Comment: I get you. You mean that the test should be reversed when the end date crosses year boundary. In other words: when the end date is earlier in a year than the start date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableWithDates t WHERE month(t.start) >= 11 AND month(t.finish) < 3
```

if you want the first of march it will go like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableWithDates t WHERE month(t.start) >= 11 AND (month(t.finish) < 3 OR month(finish) <= 3 AND day(finish)<=1)
```

Depending on the size of the data you will run this at. You can get into performance problems, as MySQL can't use indexes of calculated columns.
If you run into this i suggest spitting the month AND/OR day into separate columns.

Edit:
Given an one parameter input as '2008-02-29'

```
SELECT * FROM tableWithDates t 
WHERE 
 month(t.start) >= month('2008-02-29') AND day(t.start) >= day('2008-02-29')
AND month(t.finish) <= month('2008-02-29') AND day(t.finish) <= day('2008-02-29')
```

Comment: start and finish are parameters.. If he inputs start as 11 and finish as 2 your query will return every record without doing any check on its date

Answer (score 0):

You can use some date extract function and then check your condition..

for example.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2013-11-01 20:38:40');
 this will give ouput start month as 11

SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2014-03-01  20:38:40');
  this will give ouput end month as 3
```

now you can check the condition from above two result..